# Any way to have a 'send to -> mail recipient' menu entry point to Gmail?

Tags: windows-xp, gmail, send-to

I'm using Windows XP Pro, and I currently have a contextual menu in Explorer with a 'Send to -> mail recipient' entry that launches Outlook.  I would like it to launch Gmail instead. Is that possible ?

I already have Gmail associated with 'mailto:' links, but that's not enough...

Comment: see this: http://superuser.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-use-gmail-as-my-primary-e-mail-client

Comment: I have also associated the "mailto:" action with my gmail already and I do believe you **CAN** create your own action by going in any folder window to: *Tools > Folder Options > File Types (tab) and look for "MAPMAIL"*. I'm looking for the answer myself, hence I don't know what to put in there or what to do with it... I am sure there is a way of resolving this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[How Do I Attach a File in Gmail From the Windows Context Menu?](http://lifehacker.com/5177419/how-do-i-attach-a-file-in-gmail-from-the-windows-context-menu)

> You can integrate Gmail or even Yahoo email directly into Windows using the previously mentioned Affixa application, which registers itself as the default email application on your computer and handles file uploading to Gmail.

This is [a full list of Affixa features](http://www.affixa.com/Features.aspx).

Comment: Seems to work. Did not succeed yet to have it use FF instead of IE.

Comment: Weird. I've just checked and it does on my machine. Affixa adds its extensions to Firefox - have you restarted the browser?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible.

Yahoo! mail got that feature, but I have not seen it advertised from GMail.