# How do I use GMail as my primary e-mail client?

Tags: windows, email, gmail

I use the [GMail](http://mail.google.com) web interface for my e-mail needs. How do I get mailto: style links in web pages and "send mail" type actions in Windows programs to open up the GMail web site?

I need this to work across and outside of browsers, so an extension for Firefox won't cut it.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/223/any-way-to-have-a-send-to-mail-recipient-menu-entry-point-to-gmail

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google has a "[Google Notifier](http://toolbar.google.com/gmail-helper/notifier_windows.html)" program just for this. It runs in the tray on Windows and lets you set Gmail as your default mail program. It also provides notifications when you get new e-mail.

Comment: Note that you get an error if you have HTTPS always enabled.  Here's a link to fix it: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=9429

Comment: Notifier only works for mail hyperlinks (e.g. `mailto:`). For using gmail as a client outside of hyperlinks, e.g. *R-click > Send To > Mail recipient* see related question http://superuser.com/questions/573568/gmail-as-default-windows-mail-program-not-same-as-mailto

Answer (score 4):

You can use [gmailto firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/12201) to have "mailto:" links handled by gmail.

Or better, [set it up without an extension](http://lifehacker.com/392287/set-firefox-3-to-launch-gmail-for-mailto-links), in Firefox.

For the rest of the system, you'll need to have a wrapper application that launches gmail.

Comment: I can't vote down, but I think he said "no firefox extensions". =P