# Why does nothing happen when I set Windows XP's mailto handler to chrome?

Tags: windows-xp, email, mailto

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use GMail as my primary e-mail client?](https://superuser.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-use-gmail-as-my-primary-e-mail-client)

I tried to edit Windows XP's mailto settings by going to `Folder Options > File Types > URL:MailTo Protocol` and changing the command for the "open" action.

Initially, it was set to this:

```
"C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\OFFICE11\OUTLOOK.EXE" -c IPM.Note /m "%1"
```

This worked as expected, opening a compose window in Outlook with the specified email address.

I changed it to this:

```
"C:\Path\To\chrome.exe" "https://mail.google.com/?view=cm&fs=1&to=%1"
```

But now when I click on `mailto` links, nothing happens.

If I paste the same line into `cmd.exe`, and replace the `%1` with an email address, it works as intended (opening a compose window in Gmail with the specified email address). So why doesn't it work when I click `mailto` links?

Comment: My guess is that the MailTo protocol doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the commment, but I should of been more specific and less sarcastic.  Note, you are passing the **whole URL** through `%1`

It passes the URL `mailto:Blah blah blah` to the applications.

So the command executed is: `C:\Path\To\chrome.exe" "https://mail.google.com/?view=cm&fs=1&to=mailto:Mathew@SuperUser.com"`.

What you need to do is download Google's Gmail extension or get one from the Chrome store.  There are literally 100 of them also.

If you know C/Delphi/C++/Any native coder, you can write a shell extension that parses the URL.

Comment: Well, it's a Mail.Google.com URL, probably to the *compose new email* page (I'm not a Gmail user). Shouldn't that work to open Gmail?

Comment: @DanielBeck: I haven't googled it, but the correct url should be `... to=Mathew@SuperUser.com`. I know it shouldn't have the protocol in there.

Comment: Now that makes sense. You're right, of course.