# Can I make Gmail the default 'send mail to recipient' program in Word 2007?

Tags: windows, email, gmail, microsoft-word-2007

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use GMail as my primary e-mail client?](https://superuser.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-use-gmail-as-my-primary-e-mail-client)

Can I make Gmail the default 'send mail to recipient' program in Word 2007?

Now that Outlook is not sold with the Office package, I would like to make Gmail the program that quick command opens by default.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this. On Windows, you will have to start with [Gmail Notifier](http://toolbar.google.com/gmail-helper/notifier_windows.html).

After that is installed, right-click the Notifier icon in your system tray, and select Options. Then check the box next to *Use Gmail for internet mailto: links*.

After you have clicked OK and accepted the changes, this should make Gmail pop up when you want to send direct emails from your program menus (Word, etc.)

Comment: FYI - GMail notifier only takes over mailto: URLs, it doesn't support "Simple MAPI".  What this means to you as a user (for non-developers) is that any program that uses simple MAPI to send email (most that send file attachments use MAPI), will not use GMail and will continue to use your default email client.  The mailto: URL is pretty much only used by email hyperlinks or typing mailto: in the Windows Run box, not any "send as attachment" options in apps.